# How to retrieve photo library path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, photolibrary

I am using photos saved in photo library in my application.
how can I retrieve path of photos saved in photo library?

I had converted that `UIImage` into `NSData` and saved that data in application's sandbox(in one file).Using sqlite , I have created a database and saving file path in database.
Whenever i need image, I retrieve `NSData` from file path saved in database.

```
    NSMutableData *data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];    
data    =UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImageimageNamed:@"image.png"]);        
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);    
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];     
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"first.txt"];  [data writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];     
NSString *m=[[@"'"stringByAppendingFormat:filePath]stringByAppendingFormat:@"'"]; 
NSString *query=[[@"INSERT INTO newtable (image) VALUES (" stringByAppendingFormat:m]stringByAppendingFormat:@")"]; 
NSLog(@"query....%@",query);        
[obj configureDatabase:@"Editerdb.rdb"];//function to configure database 
[obj insertInTable:query];// function to insert into db
```

This code is working.
Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all in the first line you are going to have a memory leak. Check the documentation on `UIImagePNGRepresentation` to for assistance. so remove the the first line of code. and use `NSData` instead of `NSMutableData` coz you are not changing the contents of image.

and second of all you are not saving the image path in database but the image itself again for this referrer to documentation on `UIImagePNGRepresentation` so when to want to image just retrive the `NSData` object from database and convert the `NSData` to `UIImage` using `imageWithData:`

Comment: Thanks.But how can i save NSData in database?(means in which format...(varchar,integer????))

Comment: well sorry for that part but i have not used the sqllite by my self. but you can make a txt file to save the image. google for how to make a text file in iphone

Comment: follow this link http://howtomakeiphoneapps.com/2009/06/reading-and-writing-text-files-in-iphone-os-3-0/

Comment: You can save the data of image in BLOB type in SQLite.That would be helpful.